# NHibernate Second Level Cache With NHibernate Linq Provider 1.0

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

How to enable NHibernate Second-Level Cache with NHibernate Linq Provider 1.0 ?

Second-Level Cache seems to work only with ICriteria usage.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, I finally worked this one out:

```
public IQuerable<T> CreateLinqQuery()
{
    var query = session.Linq<T>();
    query.QueryOptions.SetCachable(true);
    return query;
}
```

**Update**
As others have pointed out, in NH3, use query.Cacheable().
However be very careful to do it like this:

```
// Correct way:
query = query.Cacheable();

// This won't work:
query.Cacheable();
```

Answer (score 21):

For NHibernate 3+  it's `session.Query<T>().Cacheable()`

Answer (score 3):

NH3 RC version:

```
public IQueryable<T> Queryable<T>()
{
    IQueryable<T> queryable = SessionFactory.OpenSession().Queryable<T>();
    queryable = queryable.Cacheable<T>();

    return queryable;
}
```