# How to enable second level cache in ActiveRecord Linq?

Tags: nhibernate, caching, castle-activerecord, linq-to-nhibernate, activerecordlinq

Second level cache can be enable using [`QueryOptions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375255/nhibernate-second-level-cache-with-nhibernate-linq-provider-1-0). But how could be enabled in Castle ActiveRecord Linq? `ActiveRecordLinq` class does not have such a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think QueryOptions applied only for the old Linq provider (pre NH 3). With NH 3 you have to call `Cacheable()` on the `IQueryable<T>`. I'm pretty sure you can apply the same method to an IQueryable returned by ActiveRecord.

Comment: @Mauricio: `ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable<MyEntity>()` does not have `Cacheable()` method or property. Would you please show in a sample?

Comment: @afsharm: `Cacheable()` is an extension method in the NHibernate.Linq namespace, it applies to any `IQueryable<T>`, so it should also apply here.

Comment: @afsharm: I'm talking about NHibernate 3 here

Comment: @Mauricio: But Castle ActiveRecord I'm using is based on NHibernate 2.1.2, is there any work-around?

Comment: @Mauricio: I'm not sure yet that Castle ActiveRecord 3 is stable and production ready or not. Additionally it seems that AR 3 is based on .Net Framework 4. But my Castle ActiveRecord based applications are based on .Net Framework 3.5 and can not be upgraded to .Net Framework 4.

Comment: @afsharm: Castle ActiveRecord 3 is also available for .net 3.5